# Nested backbone model results in infinite recursion when saving

Tags: backbone.js

This problem just seemed to appear while I updated to Backbone 1.1.  I have a nested Backbone model:

```
var ProblemSet = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        open_date: "",
        due_date: ""},
    parse: function (response) {
        response.name = response.set_id;
        response.problems = new ProblemList(response.problems);
        return response; 
    }
});

var ProblemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Problem
});
```

I initially load in a ProblemSetList, which is a collection of ProblemSet models in my page. Any changes to the open_date or due_date fields of any ProblemSet, first go to the server and update that property, then returns.  This fires another change event on the ProblemSet.

It appears that all subsequent returns from the server fires another change event and the changed attribute is the "problems" attribute.   This results in infinite recursive calls.

The problem appears to come from the part of set method of Backbone.Model (code listed here from line 339)

```
// For each `set` attribute, update or delete the current value.
for (attr in attrs) {
    val = attrs[attr];
    if (!_.isEqual(current[attr], val)) changes.push(attr);
    if (!_.isEqual(prev[attr], val)) {
      this.changed[attr] = val;
    } else {
      delete this.changed[attr];
    }
    unset ? delete current[attr] : current[attr] = val;
  }

  // Trigger all relevant attribute changes.
  if (!silent) {
    if (changes.length) this._pending = true;
    for (var i = 0, l = changes.length; i < l; i++) {
      this.trigger('change:' + changes[i], this, current[changes[i]], options);
    }
  }
```

The comparison on the problems attribute returns false from _.isEqual() and therefore fires a change event.

My question is: is this the right way to do a nested Backbone model?  I had something similar working in Backbone 1.1. Other thoughts about how to proceed to avoid this issue?

Comment: I understand you have `save` bound to the model's `change` event?

Comment: Yes.  It's like:

    problemSets.on("change",function(_set){
         _set.save();});

Comment: My latest thought that it isn't a problem with backbone 1.1, but rather underscore that also updated to 1.5.2 and with it some changes to the _.isEqual function with objects.

Comment: More exploring has led me to the following:  the Backbone.js code that I cited above is returning a changes variables meaning that there are differences between the current object and the one just sent from the server.  It appears that the reason why is that the ids of the new objects are different than the old ones; I'm thinking because they went through the parse command (listed above) and a new ProblemList was created.

A new pair of questions might be: for a nested model like this, should I not make a new ProblemList collection (and keep the old ids) or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reinstantiate your `problems` attribute each time your `model.fetch` completes, the objects are different and thus trigger a new cycle.

What I usually do to handle nested models:

- use a model property outside of the attributes handled by Backbone,
- instantiate it in the `initialize` function,
- `set` or `reset` this object in the parent `parse` function and return a response omitting the set data

Something like this:

```
var ProblemSet = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        open_date: "",
        due_date: ""
    },
    initialize: function (opts) {
        var pbs = (opts && opts.problems) ? opts.problems : [];
        this.problems = new ProblemList(pbs);
    },
    parse: function (response) {
        response.name = response.set_id;
        if (response.problems)
            this.problems.set(response.problems);
        return _.omit(response, 'problems');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If you have a chance, another general question I have is how to store the nested model.  It appears that you have it as a field of the object (ProblemSet for example) instead of in the attributes list.  Is the way you listed above a preferable way?

Comment: @PeterStaab Vastly subjective, but I prefer it that way because, as your problem demonstrated, I don't want the underlying objects to change when I reset/fetch/fry the attributes (or introduce conditions everywhere) and I feel its' easier and cleaner to handle. Of course, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it

Answer (score 0):

parse gets called on fetch and save (according to backbone documentation), this might cause your infinite loop. I don't think that the parse function is the right place to create the new ProblemsList sub-collection, do it in the initialize function of your model instead.

Comment: Creating Nested Backbone models/collections inside `parse` is an established practice

Comment: oh, thanks for that hint, did not see this before ;)